# How do I 'monkey patch' or override User.is_authenticated()? Creates issues with using django-lazysignup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, monkeypatching

I installed django-lazysignup and am facing the challenge now of User.is_authenticated() returning True, for what are not *actually* authenticated users, but instead lazy-signup users.  I can update any checks for User.is_authenticated() in my code with my own function.  However, other packages like django-allauth, check this method to decide whether a user is already signed-in, and redirect from attempts to reach the login page.

```
class RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            redirect_to = self.get_authenticated_redirect_url()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            return _ajax_response(request, response)
...
```

Are there any recommendations that don't require replacing is_authenticated() in every package that I include?  Seems most of them expect it to function a particular way, and django-lazysignup turns that on its head.  Could I monkey patch the User model with a new is_authenticated() method?  If it's possible, where would I do this so that it's attached to the page request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just having to replace all calls to User.is_authenticated().

To prevent django-allauth from redirecting lazy-users from the login page, this ended up looking something like this:

```
from allauth.account.views import AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin

def _ajax_response(request, response, form=None):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if (isinstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect)
            or isinstance(response, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect)):
            redirect_to = response['Location']
        else:
            redirect_to = None
        response = get_adapter().ajax_response(request,
                                           response,
                                           form=form,
                                           redirect_to=redirect_to)
    return response


class RedirectUserWithAccountMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        if user_has_account(request.user):
            redirect_to = self.get_authenticated_redirect_url()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            return _ajax_response(request, response)
        else:
            response = super(RedirectUserWithAccountMixin,
                             self).dispatch(request,
                                            *args,
                                            **kwargs)
        return response

    def get_authenticated_redirect_url(self):
        redirect_field_name = self.redirect_field_name
        return get_login_redirect_url(self.request,
                                      url=self.get_success_url(),
                                      redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name)

class LoginView(RedirectUserWithAccountMixin,
            AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin,
            FormView):
...
```

Where user_has_account() was my own method for checking whether the user was actually signed in.

Answer (score 0):

`django-lazysignup`, which you are using, allows you to deliver a custom LazyUser class ([here](https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup/blob/master/lazysignup/constants.py#L4)). All you need to do is to write a subclass of `lazysignup.models.LazyUser` with defined `is_authenticated` method and set it as `settings.LAZYSIGNUP_USER_MODEL`.

But this is not the end of your troubles. Lots of django apps 
assume that authenticated user has some properties. Mainly, `is_staff`, `is_superuser`, `permissions`, `groups`. First and foremost, `django.contrib.admin` needs them to check if it can let the user in and what to show him. Look how [`django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L374) mocks them and copy it. Remark: look how `AnonymousUser` is **not** subclassing any user class nor `db.Model`. Supplied user class only needs to quack.

Comment: Thanks Łukasz, this is a much better solution to monkey patching.  I'll give it a shot and post any updates.

Comment: I got as far as subclassing LazyUser, but settings.LAZYSIGNUP_USER_MODEL seems strictly used for referencing a custom User model, not a custom LazyUser model.  I'm avoiding a custom User model because of all the warnings here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model